# Angular Material Expansion Panel lazy rendering

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I saw in their docs that they now have lazy rendering for the accordian expansion panels but I can't seem to get it to work. I tried their example but it doesn't seem to load. Has anyone gotten this working yet?

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsmfjr-z1uw86?file=app/expansion-overview-example.html)

[Doc](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview#lazy-rendering)

Comment: it works perfectly fine. I guess

Answer (score 3):

Updated your angular material dependency to @angular/material 5.2.1. Now it works.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsmfjr-jgsyj3?file=main.ts

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Context is what I wrote : "angular dependency update". Answer is that simple. What I can do is probably add one more line. Can't write an essay for this.

Answer (score 1):

Updating @angular/material to 5.2.1 fixed it for me.